# Extract specific string from Java without using grep or split

Tags: java, csv, extract, text-extraction

I am trying to extract variables and their values from a large file.
The file has thousands of rows, and may or may not contain some values. Here is a sample file

```
student name=james age=13 city=toronto
teacher name=joe age=31 city=chicago
student age=21 city=paris
```

I am trying to extract the variable name and its value using Java. In other words, I want to get `type`, `name`, `age`, and `city`

Here is my Java Pojo

```
public class MyPOJO {
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String city;

    public MyPOJO(String type, String name, int age, String city) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.city = city;
    }
    //Getters and setters below
}
```

My problem or question is what is the best way to do this? I do not want to use grep as the content of this file may change. I would rather use something like Pojo class to extract the values.

---

My current solution uses String split, but I am looking for a more efficient method.

```
public MyPOJO extract(String line){
    String[] split = line.split(" ");
    String type, name, city;
    int age;
    type = split[0];
    for(String s : split){
        if(s.contains("name"){
            name = s.split("=")[1];
        }
        if(s.contains("city"){
            name = s.split("=")[1];
        }
        if(s.contains("age"){
            age = Integer.parseInt(s.split("=")[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for one, you can cut out unnecessary method calls by using a regular for loop, and moving the type = split[0] inside the for loop `if (i ==0) { type = split[0]; continue; }` I'm pretty sure the contains() method is O(N) for however long the string is, so avoiding 3 more extra calls of contains() should help

Comment: This is also probably not the site for this, and you should try codereview.com. Also, dont delete your previous question and repost a new one.

Comment: *each of your if statements should have a `continue;` to prevent extra calls of `.contains()`

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the file is not going to change, you can use a regex for this.

```
@Test
void parse() {
    String text = """
            student name=james age=13 city=toronto
            teacher name=joe age=31 city=chicago
            student age=21 city=paris
            """;

    String regex = "(student|teacher)\\s+(name=(\\w+)\\s+)?age=(\\d+)\\s+city=(\\w+)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    List<MyPOJO> pojos = pattern.matcher(text)
            .results()
            .map(match -> new MyPOJO(
                    match.group(1),
                    match.group(3),
                    Integer.parseInt(match.group(4)),
                    match.group(5)
            ))
            .toList();

    System.out.println(pojos);
}
```

briefly, this is what the regex is looking for:

`(student|teacher)` matches either "student" or "teacher";

`\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters;

`(name=(\w+)\s+)?` is an optional group that matches "name=" followed by one or more word characters, followed by one or more whitespace characters;

`age=(\d+)` matches "age=" followed by one or more digits;

you can read more about regex here: https://www.baeldung.com/regular-expressions-java

Comment: just curious, but would the regex account for if the name age and city are out of order?

Comment: probably not, feel free to run the test locally and twitch the regex

Comment: ooo. i m not very good with regex, so I refrain from doing any overly complicated regex haha. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you could possibly not use the POJO and consider all the values as String, then following would be an efficient implementation.

```
public static Map<String, String> extract(String line) {
    Map<String, String> parsedLine = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] allTokens = line.split(" ");
    parsedLine.put("type", allTokens[0]);
    for (int index = 1; index < allTokens.length; index++) {
        String[] tokenParts = allTokens[index].split("=");
        parsedLine.put(tokenParts[0], tokenParts[1]);
    }
    return parsedLine;
}
```